# Python, code to csv. Troubles

Tags: python, csv, output

first of all wanna say that I've been researching the forum for about 2 days and didn't find anything that suits me.
Well, here we go. Im scrapping a website and I just need to set up the output of the python code in order.

this is what I got after running it:

```
1 
Kidderminster Harr
1183
283
138
170
1005
731
""
208
148
236
813
877
""
+210
1727
.536
```

In a single column..

And this is what I want: I want a csv like this

```
1, Kidderminster Harr, 1183, 283, 138, 170, 1005, 731, "", 208, 148, 236,etc...
```

Some time ago, I remember that adding +',' to each element would make the trick... now I don´t know why is not working anymore..

This is what I have so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = requests.get('http://www.statto.com/football/stats/england/national-league/all-time-table', headers={'User-Agent':'a-user-agent'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text)
summary = soup.find("div",{"id" : "page-content"})
tables = summary.find('table')
count = 0
for row in tables.findAll('tr'):
    for cell in row.findAll('td'):
        data = cell.getText()
        if (count < 18):
            data = data + ';'
            print data
        count += 1
        if (count==19):
            print data
        count = 0
```

Any ideas would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print data
```

Prints data and a newline.

```
print data,
```

suppresses the newline.
Does that help?

I think you want:

```
if (count < 18):
    data = data + ","
    print data,
    count += 1
elif (count==19):
    print data
    count = 0
```

There are more pythonic ways to do this, but this was the answer to your question I think.

Comment: that's what I talking about!! thanks man!! I've been 3 days getting crazy and it was just I forgot to put that ',' after the print!

Comment: Python 3 and/or "from __future__ import print_function" give you the print function versus the print statement. This you can pass an "end" parameter such as end="" to suppress the newline. But in python 2 this is how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to split on the whitespace, then join by commas:

```
>>> string =  "1 Kidderminster Harr 1183 283 138 170 1005 731 "" 208 148 236 813 877 "" +210 1727 .536"
>>> ", ".join(string.split())
'1, Kidderminster, Harr, 1183, 283, 138, 170, 1005, 731, 208, 148, 236, 813, 877, +210, 1727, .536'
```

The `split` method will split the string into a list by its whitespace, then `join` creates a string with each list member separated by `", "`.

Edit: Your question has changed a bit, but if you can append each part of your column to a list then call the `join`.

Answer (score 0):

looking at your code you first need to initialize a result string like so:

```
result = ""
```

do that before the second for loop.  then you need to add to that loop in the two places where you print the data variable

```
result = result + data + ", "
```

and

```
result = result + data
```

and then right after that second line

```
print result
```

you should get what you need.